# Azure PolyBase external table from StorageTable

Tags: azure, sql-server-2016, azure-synapse, polybase

Can somebody explain to me why I can polybase reference an azure BlobStorage as external table but not an azure StorageTable?
Did I missed it some where in the documentary? Its some kind of ironic for me if I don't missed it and it is really not possible.

## **Related to @wBob answer**

I created a uservoice idea, please vote if you found this is a feature that is missing:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/19014286-support-of-storagetable-as-datasource

Comment: I found [this blog](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/azure-odbc-polybase.rst) that sets it up using a system DSN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Table Storage can store more No-SQL structures so is potentially more complicated than your average flat-file.  Even different rows can have different schemas as per [this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-table-design-guide).  Polybase on the other hand is optimised for highly-structured flat files and loading high volume at high speed.  It has a fairly simple interface where you can set the file type, separators, a few failure options, but not much else.  So in answer to your question, Table Storage data could potentially be more complicated than could be optimised for high speed loading via a simple interface like Polybase.

However this is not a problem as Azure Data Factory can import from Table Storage:

[image: Azure Data Factory with Azure Table Storage]

Polybase has recently been extended to support [Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/sql-data-warehouse-now-supports-seamless-integration-with-azure-data-lake-store/).  If you feel strongly about this, you could post a feedback request:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse